# How to produce individual key and values to kafka topic from the list of keys and values

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

`KStream<List<keys>, List<values>> mapValues = stream.selectKey((key, value) ->  util.fetchKeys(key, value))  .mapValues(value ->  util.fetchValues(value)) ;`

Above is my code snippet. Here I want to loop through each key and value, produce to my topic using

`.to("out-topic", keySerdes, valueSerdes)`.

Here keySerdes, valueSerdes are in avro converted

Please let me know, if there is any way to get this done.

Thanks in advance!

Tried flattening to get the keys and values didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is change your topology to something like this:

`stream.transform(() -> new MyTransformer()).to("out-topic", keySerde, valueSerde)`

and the `Transformer` instance would look something like this:

```
MyTransformer<key, value> implements Transformer<key, value> {
  ProcessorContext context;

 void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
 }

 Void<value> transform(key, value) {
    List<key> keys  = util.fetchKeys(key);
    List<value> values = util.fetchValues(value);
    //assumes both lists have the same length
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
      //forwards each key-value to the sink node
      context.forward(keys.get(i), values.get(i)
    }
  return null; //filtered out by Kafka Streams - not forwarded

  void close() { }
}
```

If you are using Kafka Streams v. 3.0 or higher, `transform` is deprecated, so in that case, swap out `transform` for the newer [process](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named-java.lang.String...-) operator but overall, the principal is the same.

HTH,
Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill, Just made few updates to the above code snippet and worked fine!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out for you!